# PowerShell increment an array of type System.Object

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop

Me and PowerShell arrays are having some difficulties today and I'm hoping someone can lend me a hand.

I'm looking to run PowerShell's Switch command to alter this code block, which will run on Monday:

```psh
for ($i = 1; $i -le 7; $i++)
{
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($i))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " " + "1:00 am".ToUpper())
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString("").ToUpper()
My-Function -date $d2 -day $d3 -dayofweek $d4
}
```

That code works as expected, however the difficulties come in when I'm trying to adjust things, as seen below:

```psh
$i=@(-1,0,1,2,3,4,5)
for ($i -le 7; $i++){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($i))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " " + "1:00 am".ToUpper())
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString("").ToUpper()
}
```

But that code returns the following error text, also trying `[int]$i=@(-1,0,1,2,3,4,5)` also doesn't work.  That returns `Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".At line:1 char:1`

```
The '++' operator works only on numbers. The operand is a 'System.Object[]'.At line:2 char:16
+ for ($i -le 7; $i++){
+                ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperatorRequiresNumber
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is correct. $i is an array and you're trying to invoke the ++ operator on it and that is not supported.  I think you want this

```psh
$array = -1,0,1,2,3,4,5
foreach ($i in $array) {
    $d = (Get-Date).AddDays($i)
    $d2 = $d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM"
    $d3 = $d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $d4 = $d.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper()
}
```

Comment: Yup yup, after much begging and yelling at PowerShell, I recalled foreach and now I know you can run `foreach` against a collection of numbers!  Thanks @Keith